# implementation of KD Tree in sk learn

Tags: scikit-learn, kdtree

I am curious how the kd-tree is built in sk learn. I  have already looked up in web and found [kdtree](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/kd_tree.pyx) But unfortunately it cant be the implemenation, because in KD Tree from sklearn there is a method quer_range[sk KDtree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.query_radius) and there not. Is there a site where i can look up the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's splitted across multiple files.

In the beginning of your linked file you will see:

```
cdef class KDTree(BinaryTree)
```

meaning, that it's inheriting from `BinaryTree`, which defines the [function you mentioned](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bf58465b3382caa096adda82304284e6bab01eca/sklearn/neighbors/binary_tree.pxi#L1358).

Also some comments within this (BinaryTree) file:

```
# Implementation Notes
# --------------------
# This implementation uses the common object-oriented approach of having an
# abstract base class which is extended by the KDTree and BallTree
# specializations.
#
# The BinaryTree "base class" is defined here and then subclassed in the BallTree
# and KDTree pyx files. These files include implementations of the
# "abstract" methods.
```

So within this special file, you linked to, some abstract methods are defined which are enough to make the `query_radius`-method from the base-class work.